# How can I merge 2 (or more) columns into a new one for each SQL row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For example:

```
Field1 | Field2 | Field3 |
--------------------------
  the  |  lazy  |  dog
```

into

```
Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | History
--------------------------------------
  the  |  lazy  |  dog   |  thelazydog
```

Don't care about spaces etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like :

```
INSERT INTO Table (Field1, Field2, Field3, History) 
                  (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field1+Field2+Field3)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting incorrect syntax near Field1. Any clues why? My table name is 2005_New and I'm using it like 
INSERT INTO [2005_New] (Field1, Field2, Field3, History) 
                  (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field1+Field2+Field3)

Comment: @dqm what DBMS are you using ? SQL Server ?

Comment: Yes. Also, in case of NULL entries, the result is NULL. How can I skip the columns that contain NULL but include all the others?

Comment: Make sure you understand what coalesce does. You need to wrap each column in a coalesce, not the whole list.

Answer (score 2):

Use a virtual column.  to handle summing null values use isNull.

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  , field1 smallint
  , field2 smallint
  , field3 smallint
  , history AS isnull(field1,0) + isnull(field2,0) + isNull(field3,0)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
, field1 + field2 + field 3 as history
into **put table name here**
from tblName
```

That's if you want it in a new table.  If you just want to select the results, take out the 'into' line.